# Apple Mach O-Linker Warning -F not a directory

Tags: ios

I get a copy of a xcode project. If I run the project I get following warning

```
warning: path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib' following -F not a directory
```

how to fix this warning? 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Well… does that directory exist? It appears you're not specifying a directory, but rather a dylib, and -F wants a directory.

Comment: Where I have to specify the directory ? In the Search Path?

Comment: Somewhere in your project settings… not really something that can be effectively helped with via internet. You should talk with whoever you got the project from.